# Updating existing Parse object in Cloud Code

Tags: parse-platform

I am using Parse for my backend and want to search for existing friend requests and update those instead of creating new ones (if there is already an existing one).

I thought I figured out how to do it but when I submit new friend requests they get created as new objects instead of updating the old one, even though I found an existing request.

Here is the code I am using:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("FriendRequest", function(request, response) {

    //search for an existing friend request with the same "from" and "to" 
    var query = new Parse.Query("FriendRequest");
        query.equalTo("from", request.object.get("from"))
        .equalTo("to", request.object.get("to"));

    query.find({
      success: function(results) {
        if(results.length > 0)
        {
         var result = results[0];

         //the new request id is undefined as expected
         console.log("request id: " + request.object.id);

         //the result id is valid for an object in the db as expected
         console.log("result id: " + results[0].id);

         //set the id of the request to the id of the existing db object
         request.object.id = results[0].id;

         //the valid id is now in the request object id
         console.log("request id: " + request.object.id);

             //after response.success, the database shows a new entry
             //with a different id
         //instead of updating the existing entry
         response.success();
         }
         }
    });

});
```

There isn't a lot going on here. The query does come back successful with the correct entry in the database.  I can confirm that I get the correct objectId for the existing item in the database.  Any thoughts or ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't manually set the `objectId` of an object.

If you want `beforeSave` to NOT create a new object (which is what you're about to do when `beforeSave` is called), you need to manually update the existing object and then respond with a failure. If you respond with `response.success()`, the object will be saved normally.

In your code, you don't seem to make any changes to the existing object. All you really need to do is to return `response.error` (https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-onsave)

Of course, you should also handle this in your code somehow. Either by alerting the user, or handling it silently.

However; why does your code attempt to save a new friend request if one already exist? Your app should know that one exists and disable the friend request button or whatever the UI offers.

Comment: Hi!  Thank you for the comment.  Well, I got the idea to set the objectId from the Parse forums, in an post over a year old but it was from one of their employees so I figured it would work.  The code I posted has had a lot of things removed because I was trying to figure out why it wasn't working, so I wanted to eliminate unnecessary things.  What I am really wanting to do is update the status of the request (for example, accepted or denied).  So the request sent in is actually different than the one I query for.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I am wrong on the manually set objectId part. Do you have a link to that post?

Comment: Oh, it looks like you are right.  I got the idea from this post:  https://parse.com/questions/how-can-i-upsert  But the comment where they tried to set the objectId was not from a Parse employee.